# Get libev remote ip address from this example code?

Tags: c, libevent, libev

I'm trying to learn libevent/libev (in this case its libev) from the following link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-libev/

I'm wondering how to find out what the remote ip address is so I can build my own DHT.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the **incoming** structure but I just don't know.

Here is the callback code that the incoming variable is used, for the rest of the code click the link above.

```
void buf_read_callback(struct bufferevent *incoming,
                       void *arg)
{
  struct evbuffer *evreturn;
  char *req;

  req = evbuffer_readline(incoming->input);
  if (req == NULL)
    return;

  evreturn = evbuffer_new();
  evbuffer_add_printf(evreturn,"You said %s\n",req);
  bufferevent_write_buffer(incoming,evreturn);
  evbuffer_free(evreturn);
  free(req);
}
```

Basically the example code provides a "server" driven by libev events, you can connect to the server by telneting the server ip:port pair and it will just echo back everything you say to it -- Notice the line that says "You said %s\n"

Comment: `evbuffer_readline` is from libevent, not libev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the remote address when calling `accept()` and then associate that with the new connection instead. However, you could also just use [`getpeername()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpeername.html) in your callback. There's nothing special that libev will do regarding this, just take the FD number and do network programming like you always do it in C.

Comment: Nice, that makes more sense than i had originally thought

Answer (score 0):

There is example:

```
struct sockaddr_in ip_adr_get;
int ip_adr_len;

ip_adr_len = sizeof(ip_adr_get);
getpeername(fd, &ip_adr_get, &ip_adr_len);

printf("IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip_adr_get.sin_addr));
printf("Port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(ip_adr_get.sin_port));
```